# Как сделать окно ответа при нажатии на кнопку на JS

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть следующая кнопка:

```
<button class="btn-u btn-large ">Ответить</button>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку под ней появлялась HTML форма?

Comment: Можете добавлять на страницу сразу под кнопкой форму ввода и кнопку, и при нажатии на нужную кнопку - показывать форму. Либо при нажатии создавать форму (или подгружать аяксом) и вставлять на страницу под кнопкой.

Comment: как вы сами пытались решить задачу ? где Ваш код с минимальным желанием решить задачу самостоятельно? что пробовали почитать по данному вопросу ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function out() {
  var p = document.getElementById('out');
  p.innerHTML = 'Hello';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\test\style\main.css">
  <script src="D:\test\js\adaptiveMenu.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">
    <button onclick="out()" class="btn-u btn-large">Ответить</button>
    <hr>
    <p id="out"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Размещаем на странице где нужно в блоке с `display: none;` свою форму, а при нажатии на кнопку - убираем это свойство у блока
2. Размещаем на странице где нужно пустой блок, при нажатии на кнопку отправляем ajax запрос на необходимый адрес, где генерируется код формы, а в success ajax'a прописываем вставку полученного ответа в свой пустой блок.

2-й вариант предпочтителен, так как форма не будет занимать место на странице при загрузке страницы. Если в форме всего пара инпутов, да и сама она одна на странице, то это не даст большого преимущества, но вот если у вас таких кнопок с формой для каждой на странице огромное количество - то оптимизация будет на лицо.

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте обработчик событий onclick на кнопку. И в теле обработчика управляйте свойством display формы.

https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events